# Query For Getting the First Entered Field For Every User

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL Table with the following structure called daily_measurements

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| date       | datetime | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| weight     | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| bicep      | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| chest      | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| waist      | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| neck       | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| thigh      | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| hips       | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| shoulders  | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| knee       | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| ankle      | float    | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| created_on | datetime | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I need to retrieve a list of every user's weight for there first and last entry.

I've tried various combinations of GROUP BY, MIN(date), MAX(date), etc. but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it efficiently.

The only way I've been able to get this to work is to do the following query on the users table, w/ 2 subqueries, but since there are aprox 30,000 users and > 200,000  measurements the query chokes up pretty bad.

```
SELECT u.id,
(SELECT user_id, weight, date FROM daily_measurements WHERE user_id = u.id ORDER BY date DESC limit 1) as starting_weight,
(SELECT user_id, weight, date FROM daily_measurements WHERE user_id = u.id ORDER BY date ASC limit 1) as ending_weight
FROM users u
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe this helps http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: Thanks for the link ... added it to my instapaper list to read up on later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
SELECT
  u1.user_id,
  u2.first_entry_weight,
  u1.weight             AS last_entry_weight
FROM daily_measurements u1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
                u1.user_id,
                u1.weight              AS first_entry_weight,
                u2.fe,
                u2.le
              FROM daily_measurements u1
                INNER JOIN (SELECT
                              daily_measurements.user_id,
                              MIN(date_entry)            fe,
                              MAX(date_entry)            le
                            FROM daily_measurements
                            GROUP BY daily_measurements.user_id) u2
                  ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
                    AND u1.date_entry = u2.fe) u2
    ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
      AND u1.date_entry = u2.le
```

Answer (score 0):

can not test it and it's performance at the moment but I thing u can start from the following query:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(d.weight AS CHAR) ORDER BY d.date ASC ), ',', 1 ) as starting_weight,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(d.weight AS CHAR) ORDER BY d.date DESC), ',', 1 ) as ending_weight
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN daily_measurements as d ON (u.id = d.user_id)
```

**edit** please treat this as a suggestion for your Query...

with such amount of users "JOIN" could be hundreds times faster then two SELECT sub-queries

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select tb.* from daily_measurements tb
join (
        select user_id, MIN(date) firstDate, MAX(date) lastDate
        from daily_measurements
        group by user_id
    ) temp
    on tb.user_id = temp.user_id 
    and (tb.date = temp.firstDate or tb.date = temp.lastDate)
```

The subquery will identify first date and last date rows for each user_id, and main query will fetch the rows again to get all the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.user_id,
B.weight InitialWeight,
B.`date` InitialDate,
C.weight LatestWeight,
C.`date` LatestDate
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id,MIN(id) idmin,MAX(id) idmax
    FROM daily_measurements GROUP BY user_id
) A 
INNER JOIN daily_measurements B ON (A.user_id=B.user_id AND A.idmin = B.id)
INNER JOIN daily_measurements C ON (A.user_id=C.user_id AND A.idmax = C.id);
```

Please make sure you have an index like this

```
ALTER TABLE daily_measurements ADD UNIQUE INDEX userid_id_ndx (user_id,id);
```

Comment: Rolando, I can't guarantee that the first id will always match the first date. User's are allowed to specify the day, for example, if they haven't logged there measurements in a week, but need to go back and add one.